# Product page tabs for short_description and description attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2

I would like to add TABS for short_description and description attribute in the product page. Now that attributes are only text.

I tried the extensions EAST TABS but has one conflict with the javascript files and cant add tab for the short_description attribute.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom theme app/design/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml and add the following code like this:

http://www.woolleydesign.net/2012/07/magento-adding-tabs-to-your-product-pages/

This link will help you to create tab..

Comment: I did everything from there but the tabs dont show. I dont know why. Maybe is another file from the theme that is in conflict with the tabs